# Passing Values from a Context View item to a new intent!

Tags: android

Sorry Im new to android, and im doing a project where i want to edit some data from a item selected in a ListView.
the prob is that i dont have any idea on how to pass the data.
I select this item, this item is of the type ProjItems(a class to construct the item);
it has the gets, string getname(), date getdata(),int getPrec();

and here is where i want to start the new Activity:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Selected Project");
    menu.add(0, DEL, Menu.NONE, R.string.remove);
    menu.add(0, EDIT, Menu.NONE, R.string.edit).setIntent(new Intent(PM_List.this, PM_Edit.class));//here is where i want to pass the info
    menu.add(0, TASK_LIST, Menu.NONE, R.string.task);
    menu.add(0, CANCEL, Menu.NONE, R.string.cancel);
    }
```

this info i want to pass to the new activity i will later show it on a textview!
Please help me, i will be very much happy, and grateful if you do!
best regards to all 
João Azevedo

Answer (score 3):

So basically you can get the selected item from the underlaying adapter like this.

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
Object my_item = getListAdapter().getItem((int) info.id);
```

And now you can pass it to the activity using the Intent that will start it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Your_Activity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putSerializable("obj_to_pass", my_item);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

And than get it from the activity in onCreate method like this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Object my_obj = extras.getSerializable("obj_to_pass");
```

Comment: 2 Questions just:
What type is the variable item on the first colum
and the getListAdapter() what it does?what i have is ProjItemAdapter, that manipulates some properties of objects of the type i want to pass!

Comment: sorry im very very new to this android and some stuff i want to learn them good :D
and i think your solution is the correct

Comment: extras.putSerializable("obj_to_pass", my_item);
and this line is gimming some probs 2 xD